# Swift 3 Warning in UICollectionViewDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3. I was designing the UICollectionView and wanted to set height and width dynamically so wanted for some answers. On the way I got this solution(Correct or not - I have No Idea):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let Labell : UILabel = UILabel()
    Labell.text =   self.items[indexPath.item]
    let labelTextWidth =   Labell.intrinsicContentSize.width
    return CGSize(width: labelTextWidth + 20, height: 35)

}
```

But this answer was in swift 2.0 And person who gave this answer claims that it is solved one. I pasted it in Xcode and changed some thing that Xcode suggested me.

Now here I am getting following warning:

```
instance method 'collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'collection(_:willDisplaySupplementaryView:forElement:at:)' of protocol 'UICollectionViewDelegate'
```

Xcode suggests me 2 solutions
1) add private ahead of func keyword
2) add @nonobjc in front of fun keyword

I tried both solutions and it suppresses the warning but none the above is never called. I tried putting break point and tried many ways. If anyone can pull me out of this pit.

Comment: i got that method func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

}

Comment: https://medium.com/@zonble/your-delegation-methods-might-not-be-called-in-swift-3-c6065ed7b4cd#.hjsujieml refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method for `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

What you're probably looking for is

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

which can be found on the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let Labell : UILabel = UILabel()
    Labell.text =   self.items[indexPath.item]
    let labelTextWidth =   Labell.intrinsicContentSize.width
    return CGSize(width: labelTextWidth + 20, height: 35)

}
```